# Data using radiobutton/Checkbox from one activity to display in another?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm making an application, which you can choose from different things using radiobuttons and checkboxes. So I'm wondering how to make the selected data appear in another activity?

This is the class where you choose what coffee you want.

```
    package com.coffee2go.coffee2go;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class coffee2 extends Activity {


    private RadioGroup choosecoffee;
    private Button order;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.coffee2);

        choosecoffee = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choosetypeofcoffee);
        order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order_coffee);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(coffee2.this, order.class));

            }
        });

        choosecoffee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(coffee2.this, order.class));
            }
        });

    }
}'
```

This is the class where I want the information to appear. The information should also be saved down to a mySQL database on the webserver 000webhost.com

```
    'package com.coffee2go.coffee2go;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class order extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup choosecoffee;
    private RadioButton bryggkaffe, latte, espresso;

    private RadioGroup sizeofcoffee;
    private RadioButton small, big;

    private CheckBox sugar, milk;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order);

        TextView orderlist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderlist);
        TextView pricelist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pricelist);
        choosecoffee = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choosetypeofcoffee);
        bryggkaffe = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.bryggkaffe);
        latte = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.latte);
        espresso = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.espresso);

        sizeofcoffee = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choosecoffeesize);
        small = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.small);
        big = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.big);

        sugar = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sugar);
        milk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.milk);

        if (bryggkaffe.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Bryggkaffe\n");

        }
        if (latte.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Latte\n");
        }

        if (espresso.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Espresso\n");
        }
        if (small.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Liten\n");
        }

        if (big.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Stor\n");
        }

        if (sugar.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Socker\n");
        }

        if (milk.isChecked() == true) {
            orderlist.append("Mjölk\n");

        }

    }'
```

Is there any way to make this? Do I need to make a connection class and a php too?

Comment: Posting your entire code with very few comments probably won't be that helpful - post where you're having trouble. What have you tried to do to get what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in the Intent to create your second activity.

Here is what you would call from your first Activity:

```
Intent orderIntent = new Intent(coffee2.this, order.class)); 
orderIntent.putExtra("CoffeeType", someVariableThatHoldsCoffeeType);
startActivity(orderIntent);
```

In your second activity (Order), you can retrieve the Coffee type from the Intent in the onCreate(...) method:

```
Intent callingActivityIntent =getIntent();
String coffeeType=sender.getExtras().getString("CoffeeType");
//Do something with the coffeeType variable
...
```

Here is a tutorial of how to pass data from start to finish:
http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/

Answer (score 0):

Gophermofer has the right idea, but it seems that you app runs like this `coffee2` -> `order` -> `coffee2`.  So rather than launch your `order` class with startActivity(), you should pass the same Intent to startActivityForResult().

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(coffee2.this, order.class), 1);
```

Once the user completes their order in `order`, use setResult() like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("Order", orderlist.getText().toString());
... // continue this for everything you want to pass back
setResult(10, intent);
finish();
```

Now back in `coffee2` setup the onActivityResult() function:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == 10) {
        String orderlist = data.getString("Order");
        // Process the order
    }
}
```

Voila! Passing information [to and from activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).